# Cannot get Autofac to work with Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I am struggling to get Autofac to work with WebApi2 controllers

I always get an error that there is no parameterless constructor

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'GatewayController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Type 'Gv8ApiGateway.Controllers.GatewayController' does not have a default constructor".....
    }
}
```

I have been through loads of posts on this online and I cant see that I have missed anything

When I look at my container after it has been built I can see that it does contain my controller

I am using TopShelf

```
    HostFactory.Run(x => //1
    {
        x.UseAutofacContainer(container);

        x.Service<IMyService>(s => //2
        {
            s.ConstructUsingAutofacContainer();
            s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
            s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
        });
        x.SetStartTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4));
        x.StartAutomatically();
        x.RunAsLocalSystem();
        x.EnableServiceRecovery(r => { r.RestartService(0); });
        x.SetDescription($"DESCRIPTION");
        x.SetDisplayName($"DISPLAY NAME");
        x.SetServiceName($"NAME");
    });
```

In my assembly module I have the line which I have verified is being called

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

In my class that is started by TopShelf I have -

```
var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(_container);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
_webApi = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:8084");
```

My Startup class is -

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );

        app.UseWebApi(config);


    }
}
```

I think the key is the place that I set the dependency resolver but it doesn't seem to make any difference where I call this, i.e. before or after I start the API

My controller is:

```
public class GatewayController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMyService_myService;

    public GatewayController(IMyService myService)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => myService);

        _myService = myService;
    }


}
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong please?

Comment: Can you add more details about "I always get an error that there is no parameterless constructor" ? Thanks

Comment: ok have added that

Comment: How about any dependencies that need to be resolved during creation of your controller? Is there a chance that any of them is not registered or registered incorrectly? Try to create parameterless constructor in your controller if it works then try to run it again with 1 dependency and this way you might find one that causes issues.

Comment: I only have 1 dependency I have verified that is in my container and is available.  If I add a parameterless constructor the controller is called but that obviously defeats the purpose

Comment: Ah, sorry you posted it in answer. What about dependencies of MyService? Message you get is standard autofac message when something cannot be resolved

Comment: MyService has all of its required dependancies because my configuration class requires the same service to be injected and that works fine, if there were dependency issues it wouldnt get there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Web API startup class shows you are using an OWIN pipeline. We see that because you're creating the `HttpConfiguration` from scratch.

`app.UseWebApi(config);`

[If you check out the documentation on Web API OWIN integration](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration) you can see an example of how that changes. **The key is that you have to set `config.DependencyResolver`, not `GlobalConfiguration.DependencyResolver`**.

As noted in the docs:

> A common error in OWIN integration is use of the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`. **In OWIN you create the configuration from scratch.** You should not reference `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` anywhere when using the OWIN integration.

Be aware there's a couple of extra steps to making sure the OWIN pipeline will work correctly with Autofac. [There are docs on setting up the base OWIN pipeline](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/owin.html) and there's additional [Autofac Web API specific middleware that needs to be added](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration)

I don't see any of the Autofac middleware in your Web API startup, so that could also cause problems. I'd recommend going back and looking at some of those docs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your service and interface in container like below.

```
container.Register<IMyService, MyService>();
```

Before TopSelf configuration setup, add above code. It will work.

Comment: Can you check your Global.asax file if it TopShelf configuration is there are not?